# Parameters in Datalab SQL modules

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

The parameterization example in the "SQL Parameters" IPython notebook in the datalab github repo (under datalab/tutorials/BigQuery/) shows how to change the value being tested for in a WHERE clause.  Is it possible to use a parameter to change the name of a field being SELECT'd on?

eg:
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT $a) AS n
        FROM [...]

After I received the answer below, here is what I have done (with a dummy table name and field name, obviously):

`%%sql --module test01
    DEFINE QUERY get_counts
    SELECT $a AS a, COUNT(*) AS n
    FROM [project_id.dataset_id.table_id]
    GROUP BY a
    ORDER BY n DESC`

`table = bq.Table('project_id.dataset_id.table_id')
    field = table.schema['field_name']
    bq.Query(test01.get_counts,a=field).sql
    bq.Query(test01.get_counts,a=field).results()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a field from a Schema object (eg. given a table, get a specific field via table.schema[fieldname]).

Or implement a custom object with a _repr_sql_ method. See: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datalab/blob/master/sources/lib/api/gcp/bigquery/_schema.py#L49

Comment: Thanks very much.  I will add some additional details to my original question about how I am doing this in case that is helpful to someone else.

Comment: Great -- the example should help others in the future!